# Cant unzip file, tested different functions

Tags: java, android, sd-card, unzip

I am unable to unzip file on sdcard. I have tested
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29
[How to unzip files programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382996/how-to-unzip-files-programmatically-in-android)
[Android - Unzip a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028421/android-unzip-a-folder)

It shows no error, no warning, nothing, like everything is okay. But zip file is not extracted.

I have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION enabled, so I can write to sdcard from app (it works, I tested that)

What can it be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php) library

With the solution by jondev you must pay attention to file paths: a single / omitted could cause nothing works

EDIT: Based on comments, probably this can help you:

```
String externalPath = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
Decompress d = new Decompress(externalPath + "/test.zip", externalPath + "/");
d.unzip();
```

Comment: `Decompress d = new Decompress("/sdcard/test.zip", "/sdcard/app/"); 
d.unzip(); `

Comment: See edit in my answer. I suppose the file test.zip is in the root directory of external storage

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, but I am a bit skeptic now, because I think that `getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()` means `"/sdcard"`

Comment: Mmmh... Did you test every stuff mentioned here ---> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal ?