# Uzip folders recursively -android

Tags: java, android, zip, unzip

I have tried to unzip a zipped file (This file contains many sub-folders and files).

```
I am not able to create sub-folders while unzipping the file.
```

Each time I am getting an error saying:

```
No such file or directory.
```

I have searched a lot about this like:

1. [Android - Unzip a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028421/android-unzip-a-folder)
2. http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/corejava/zip/ZipIsDirectory.html
3. [Unzip a zipped file on sd card in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697466/unzip-a-zipped-file-on-sd-card-in-android-application)
4. [How to unzip files recursively in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981578/how-to-unzip-files-recursively-in-java)

But, nothing helped me.

Following is what I have tried:

```
public class UnZipper {

    private static final String TAG = "UnZip";
    private String mFileName, mDestinationPath;

    public UnZipper(String fileName, String destinationPath) {
        mFileName = fileName;
        mDestinationPath = destinationPath;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return mFileName;
    }

    public String getDestinationPath() {
        return mDestinationPath;
    }

    // shrikant
    public void unzip() {
        String fullPath = mFileName;
        Log.d(TAG, "unzipping " + mFileName + " to " + mDestinationPath);
        doInBackground(fullPath, mDestinationPath);
    }

    // shrikant: I have changed return type from Boolean to boolean.
    protected boolean doInBackground(String filePath, String destinationPath) {

        File archive = new File(filePath);
        boolean returnValue = false;
        try {
            ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(archive);

            for (Enumeration e = zipfile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();) {

                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
                try {
                    unzipEntry(zipfile, entry, destinationPath);
                    Log.d("Unzipped", entry.getName());
                    returnValue = true;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG,
                            "Error while extracting file: " + entry
                                    + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while extracting file " + archive, e);
            // return false;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    // shrikant: I have changed return type from void to boolean.
    /**
     * Unzips the zipped file into outputDir path.
     * 
     * @param zipfile
     * @param entry
     * @param outputDir
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void unzipEntry(ZipFile zipfile, ZipEntry entry, String outputDir)
            throws IOException {
        Log.d("CURRENT ZIP", entry.getName());
        String _dir = null, fileName = null;
        if (entry.getName().contains("\\")) {

            _dir = entry.getName().substring(0, entry.getName().indexOf('\\'));
            createDir(new File(outputDir, _dir));
            fileName = entry.getName().substring(entry.getName().indexOf('\\'));
        }

        // Change by Prashant : To Remove "/" from file Name Date : 5/01/2011
        if (fileName.toString().startsWith("\\")) {
            fileName = fileName.substring(1); // End
        }

        if (_dir != "")
            outputDir = outputDir + "/" + _dir;

        File outputFile = new File(outputDir, fileName);
        if (!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
            createDir(outputFile.getParentFile());
        }
        Log.d("OUTPUT FILE", outputDir + fileName);
        Log.v(TAG, "Extracting: " + entry);

        Log.d("FOUND inside unzipEntry()", entry.getName());

        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                zipfile.getInputStream(entry));

// **here I am getting error.**

        BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

// **above line.**

        try {
            copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        } finally {
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }

    }

    private void createDir(File dir) {
        if (dir.exists()) {
            return;
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "Creating dir " + dir.getName());
        if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create dir " + dir);
        }
    }

    private void copy(BufferedInputStream input, BufferedOutputStream output)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int size;
        while ((size = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
            output.write(buffer, 0, size);
    }

}
```

**My question is**: (Please look at the code)

When I am calling `unzipEntry()`, when it encounters a sub-folder, it passes something like "`/data/abc.ext`", but my file system does not contain any folder named as "**data**", I even tried to create it, but failed in doing so.

> So how to create sub-folders from zipped file to destination path??

I have even tried method:

```
if(entry.isDirectory) {
// create directory
}
```

But this doesn't get called, since `unzipEntry()` (Please look in `for() loop`) directly passes the file under sub-folder.

Please help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the permission to write to SDcard set in your manifest?

Comment: what is the value of mDestinationPath ?

Comment: mDestinationPath contains the file path where unzipped files will be saved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ohh Yes! I have solved it.. :)

I have written following function that will create sub-folders recursively if required.

This is tried and tested function that will successfully unzips any file.

```
    /**
     * Unzips the file (recursively creates sub-folder if exists.)
     * 
     * @param tempFileName
     *            The zip file.
     * @param destinationPath
     *            The destination path where unzipped file will be saved.
     */
    public void unzipFile(String tempFileName, String destinationPath) {
        try {

            int index = destinationPath.lastIndexOf("\\");
            String fileString = destinationPath.substring(index);

            File extFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/courses1", fileString);
            if(!extFile.exists()) {
                createDir(extFile);
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(tempFileName);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
            ZipEntry zipentry = null;
            if (!(zin.available() == 0)) {
                byte[] startBuffer = new byte[8];

                while ((zipentry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                    String zipName = zipentry.getName();
                    if (zipName.startsWith("/")) {
                        zipName = zipentry.getName();
                    } else if (zipName.startsWith("\\")) {
                        zipName = zipentry.getName();
                    } else {
                        zipName = "/" + zipentry.getName();
                    }

                    String fileName = destinationPath + zipName;
                    fileName = fileName.replace("\\", "/");
                    fileName = fileName.replace("//", "/");

                    if (zipentry.isDirectory()) {
                        createDir(new File(fileName));
                        continue;
                    }

                    String name = zipentry.getName();
                    int start, end = 0;
                    while (true) {

                        start = name.indexOf('\\', end);
                        end = name.indexOf('\\', start + 1);
                        if (start > 0)
                            "check".toString();
                        if (end > start && end > -1 && start > -1) {
                            String dir = name.substring(1, end);

                            createDir(new File(destinationPath + '/' + dir));
                            // name = name.substring(end);
                        } else
                            break;
                    }

                    File file = new File(fileName);

                    FileOutputStream tempDexOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    int BytesRead = 0;

                    if (zipentry != null) {
                        if (zin != null) {
                            while ((BytesRead = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                tempDexOut.write(buffer, 0, BytesRead);
                            }
                            tempDexOut.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps someone. :)

Thank you.