# Unzip folder reccursively in Android Xamarin mono 3.2.6

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I got a scenario where i need to Unzip the folder recursively. 
I have gone through the several links but not matching my requirements. I'm using mono 3.2.6 and need to extract recursively in android xamarin.

I used third party tool ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip. This was working fine in my application in debugging mode. But throws an error in Release mode. After APK installation in real device.

Even tried [Dotnet.Zip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) but i'm unable unzip folder recursively.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023476/recommend-a-library-api-to-unzip-file-in-c-sharp) suggested open source dll but it is concentrated on file rather then folder

Another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747468/uzip-folders-recursively-android) which shows the solution in java android, i'm looking for the same type in c# xamarin android. 
 Is there any way to do this, even free third party tools are ok. can anybody suggest me the solution or hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is throwing error in Release mode then it may be because of the linker. To zip and unzip files you  can also use

> java.util.zip

package. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html).

Edit: Sample code

include namespace `using Java.Util.Zip;`

```
using ( ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream ( File.OpenRead ( strSourcePath ) ) )
{  
    ZipEntry theEntry;
    while ( ( theEntry = s.NextEntry ) != null )
    {
        string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName ( theEntry.Name );
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName ( theEntry.Name );
        directoryName = Path.Combine ( strDestFolderPath , directoryName );
        if ( directoryName.Length > 0 )
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory ( directoryName );
        }
        if ( fileName != String.Empty )
        {
            using ( FileStream streamWriter = File.Create ( Path.Combine ( strDestFolderPath , theEntry.Name ) ) )
            {
                int size = 2048;
                byte [] data = new byte[size];
                while ( true )
                {
                    size = s.Read ( data , 0 , data.Length );
                    if ( size > 0 )
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write ( data , 0 , size );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

where strSourcePath is source zip file path and strDestFolderPath is destination folder path

Comment: This worked for me, another solution is to add Change the linker Internalization  setting to "west" option. Android->Build->Linker->Internalization-west

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the System.IO.Compression namespace.

```
 public static async Task ExtractToDirectory(string strSourcePath, string strDestFolderPath,
        IProgress<int> progessReporter)
    {

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(File.Open(strSourcePath, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                double zipEntriesExtracted = 0;
                double zipEntries;

                zipEntries = archive.Entries.Count;

                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string fullPath = Path.Combine(strDestFolderPath, entry.FullName);
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Name))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var destFileName = Path.Combine(strDestFolderPath, entry.FullName);

                            using (var fileStream = File.Create(destFileName))
                            {
                                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                                {
                                    entryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        zipEntriesExtracted++;
                        progessReporter.Report((int)((zipEntriesExtracted / zipEntries) * 100));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);


    }
```